# Is the US $20 bill the most counterfeited?

Tags: united-states, economics, currency

In a [comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/7702/637) on "[Is it illegal to refuse US currency for a purchase?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7701/637)", @[Dan Neely](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/5878/dan-neely) said

> I don't think the main reason many businesses ban $50/100 bills is that they'd deplete their ability to make change for future customers. Minimizing losses from counterfeiters is the dominant concern.

Given the higher prevalence of $20 bills over $50 or $100 bills, I have always heard that the $20 is more frequently counterfeited in the US.

Is this true?

[Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/5521284/why-you-dont-want-to-counterfeit-the-hideous-new-100-bill) makes a throw-away claim that the $100 is the most counterfeited but with no sources.

Comment: Might need to be clear about what "most" means: by number, percentage or total value? The same *number* of counterfeit $20s is only worth 20% of that number of $100s.

Comment: @matt_black - I'll take either definition: by quantity *or* value (ideally .. both)

Comment: I always thought the idea was that the shop owner is are less willing to take a fake $100 bill than a fake $20 one.

Comment: I always heard it was the $5 bill, because they aren't worth enough to look at closely.

Comment: If you're counting face value, then you have to consider the [counterfeit $1 million bills](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-201_162-57350837/cops-man-tried-to-use-$1m-bill-at-walmart/) as well.

Comment: As a point of clarification, is this question about worldwide circulation or about the United States exclusively? Depending upon which it is I may need to modify my answer slightly.

Comment: @Rob Z - hadn't thought about the difference between global and domestic. Either, or both is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes and no**, while the $20 note is the most commonly encountered counterfeit bill in the United States, the $100 note is the most common counter fit bill in worldwide circulation.

It appears that the $20 note is typically the bill most likely to be attributed to being counterfeited in [various factoids](http://www.fuzeqna.com/ccul/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=362&ap=t) without that distinction. However, in journalistic articles that feature quotes attributed to representatives from the [United States Treasury Department](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_the_Treasury) and the [United States Secret Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secret_Service) the $100 note is cited as the [most](http://www.reuters.com/article/2010/04/21/usa-currency-idUSN2119469720100421) [commonly](http://business.time.com/2012/02/24/how-the-u-s-could-pressure-north-korea-tomorrow-quit-the-100-bill/) [counterfeited](http://www.csmonitor.com/2007/0920/p14s02-wmgn.html) in world wide circulation.

The worldwide circulation is the interesting aspect of this answer as there are a number of different techniques that are used by well-funded organizations for counterfeiting (from bleaching US$5 bills to turn into $100 note to making new ones with stolen engravings) that tend to provide indications as to where the bills are being produced.

Counterfeiting is a big enough issue that the [Federal Reserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve_System) periodically releases reports about the problem. In a report issued in [January 2000](http://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/rptcongress/counterfeit.pdf), one of the key findings was as follows:

> ... the denomination with the largest amount of counterfeits, both in
>   dollar terms (about $6 million) and as a proportion of notes processed
>   (about 60 per million notes), was the $100 note.<sup>1</sup>

---

1. See page 52 - 53 which includes a table summary of counterfeiting rates at Federal Reserve banks.

Comment: Your first reference, to Reuters is good (at least so far as fact-checked journalism goes!). I couldn't find the claim in the second reference (Time). The third one (Christian Science Monitor?!) doesn't really help your case. I'd stick to the first if I were you.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I'm in the process of slowly expanding as I want to see if I can find a press release or two from the Treasury or SS, but it will be a couple hours. With regards to the [Christian Science Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christian_Science_Monitor) they are generally accepted as a reliable newspaper despite their name.

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR: $100 notes are counterfeited more overall, but there are more low-quality $20 forgeries than low-quality $100 forgeries (by count, but not by face-value).**

The study [Estimating the Volume of Counterfeit U.S. Currency in Circulation Worldwide: Data and Extrapolation](http://www.chicagofed.org/digital_assets/publications/policy_discussion_papers/2010/PDP2010-2.pdf) contains a long evaluation of the problem.

Unfortunately, due to an unexplained error, the tables are omitted.

Through private communication with the lead author, Dr Ruth Judson, I have obtained [another copy](http://www.mediafire.com/?stztgmup493pds4) of the report. She states:

> The wording at some points might vary slightly, but the tables should be the same.

The study explains the term "circular":

> “Circular” notes are
>   those that are assigned classification numbers by the U.S. Secret Service for further
>   investigation. They are typically of higher quality than the other categories of counterfeit notes,
>   which include those printed on office copiers or computer printers or other relatively crude
>   methods.

In Table 6, we see the essential information:

[image]

*Remember that, $1,000 worth of $20 notes is five times more notes that $1,000 worth of $100 notes.*

From this table we can see that when it comes to higher-quality "circular" counterfeits, the $100 notes dominate, even after multiplying five. For the lower quality forgeries, there are more $20 notes, but they don't add up to as much value as the $100 notes.

Adding both groups together, the $100 notes win when it comes to count and value.

Comment: Non-zero 'circular' $1 bills is surprising.